# How to validate a "select" multiple of bootstrap with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi sorry for my poor English, I'm from Argentina.

I Search the web some similar theme but did not find any.
I am creating a web application and I'm using boostrap from FrontEnd and codeigniter for BackEnd. Also I'm using a custom for bootstrap for "selects", this is the link: http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

In the view I have this code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<?php echo form_label('Languages ​​supported', 'lang'); ?>
<?php $options = array('Ingles' => 'Ingles','Español' => 'Español', 'Portugués' => 'Portugués', 'Ruso' => 'Ruso', 'Francés' => 'Francés', 'Alemán' => 'Alemán', 'Italiano' => 'Italiano'); $attribute ='class="selectpicker show-tick form-control" multiple title="Seleccione los lenguajes..."'; echo form_dropdown('lang', $options, 'title',$attribute); ?>
```

This in the browser looks like this:
[View image](http://www.subeimagenes.com/img/captura-1052187.PNG)

For validation I have this code:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('lang', 'Idiomas', 'trim|required|min_length[1]|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
```

But in the database, only one value is saved. For example: In the picture above, a user selected three values ​​(Spanish, French and Portuges) but in the database only the first value that is stored (Spanish)
How to make the all values is saved in the database

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable multiple selects you have to put `[]` after `select` name:

```
<div class="form-group">
<?php echo form_label('Languages ​​supported', 'lang[]'); ?>
<?php $options = array('Ingles' => 'Ingles','Español' => 'Español', 'Portugués' => 'Portugués', 'Ruso' => 'Ruso', 'Francés' => 'Francés', 'Alemán' => 'Alemán', 'Italiano' => 'Italiano'); 
$attribute ='class="selectpicker show-tick form-control" multiple title="Seleccione los lenguajes..."'; 
echo form_dropdown('lang[]', $options, 'title',$attribute); ?>
```

In the controller:

```
$langs = '';
foreach ($this->input->post('lang') as $lang) {
    $langs .= "$lang, ";
}
$langs = rtrim ($lang, ", ");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it does not work, yet still keeps me only one value in the database